# two times setOnItemSelectedListener

Tags: android

I have 3 spinner A,B,C and I want that when the user choose element from A , B will get his item. Its work good:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> aParentView, View aView, int aPosition, long anId) {

            String selectedCompany2=String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItem());
            String selectedCompany =  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.songsArray)[spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()]; //the company name




            ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

            x="'"+selectedCompany2+"'";

            Cursor c = customersDB.rawQuery("SELECT Name, Street, Block, City  FROM "    +
                    TABLE_NAME +

                    " where Name == "+ x , null);


            if (c != null ) {
                if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Name"));
                        String street = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Street"));

                        String city = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("City"));

                        if(!results.contains(street))
                            results.add(street);

                    }while (c.moveToNext());
                }
            }

            String [] countries = results.toArray(new String[results.size()]);


            moduleOfSpecificCompany = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.degemSpinner1);
            ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter_degem = new ArrayAdapter<String>(DelekActivity.this,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, countries);           
            spinnerArrayAdapter_degem.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down vieww
            moduleOfSpecificCompany.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter_degem);





        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> aParentView) {
            // your code here

        }

    });
```

But, I also want that when the user choose something in B, the data of c will appear. I wrote this and I got an error:

```
moduleOfSpecificCompany.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> aParentView, View aView, int aPosition, long anId) {

            String selectedCompany3=String.valueOf(moduleOfSpecificCompany.getSelectedItem());
            ArrayList<String> results2 = new ArrayList<String>();


            x="'"+selectedCompany3+"'";

            Cursor c = customersDB.rawQuery("SELECT Name, Street, Block, City  FROM "    +
                    TABLE_NAME +

                    " where Name == "+ x , null);

            if (c != null ) {
                if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Name"));
                        String street = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Street"));
                        String Block = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Block"));
                        String city = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("City"));

                        if(!results2.contains(Block))
                            results2.add(Block);

                    }while (c.moveToNext());
                }
            }

            String [] countries2 = results2.toArray(new String[results2.size()]);


            /*moduleOfSpecificCompany = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.manoaSpinner1);
            ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter_manoa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(DelekActivity.this,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, countries2);          
            spinnerArrayAdapter_manoa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down vieww
            moduleOfSpecificCompany.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter_manoa);

            if (customersDB != null)
                customersDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " +   TABLE_NAME);
            customersDB.close();
**/



        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> aParentView) {
            // your code here

        }

    });
```

The code is not so relevant. The point is that when i use setOnItemSelectedListener 2 times the error appear. Thank ypi and sorry about my English.

log:

```
 10-07 01:15:30.907: D/dalvikvm(2588): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 748 objects / 55680 bytes in 242ms
10-07 01:15:45.305: D/dalvikvm(2588): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 3176 objects / 154984 bytes in 116ms
10-07 01:16:10.644: D/dalvikvm(2588): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 186 objects / 8784 bytes in 83ms
10-07 01:16:12.674: D/AndroidRuntime(2588): Shutting down VM
10-07 01:16:12.674: W/dalvikvm(2588): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
10-07 01:16:12.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2588): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-07 01:16:12.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2588): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.save_money/com.example.save_money.DelekActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-07 01:16:12.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
10-07 01:16:12.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
10-07 01:16:12.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
10-07 01:16:12.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
10-07 01:16:12.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-07 01:16:12.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-07 01:16:12.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-07 01:16:12.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-07 01:16:12.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-07 01:16:12.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-07 01:16:12.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-07 01:16:12.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-07 01:16:12.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2588): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-07 01:16:12.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at com.example.save_money.DelekActivity.onCreate(DelekActivity.java:3057)
10-07 01:16:12.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-07 01:16:12.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
10-07 01:16:12.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2588):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want data from multiple names in the query, you need to use a query like

```
SELECT Name, Street, Block, City FROM TableName WHERE Name = '1stName'
```

Then if the user selects C, you can append `OR Name = '2ndName'`

and then append a ';'

Comment: I think you domt understand my question. I need 2 listeners to 2 differnt spinners

Comment: you are right....i don't understand the question. but the error you are getting is a nullpointerexception in the oncreate method. you should make sure that you are instantiating all of your collections and that your findViewById calls are returning views.

Comment: It's look like this is the problem but its very wored. i sure moduleOfSpecificCompany is not null...

Comment: Your right!! i dont understand why but when i write again  moduleOfSpecificCompany = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.degemSpinner1); before the second listener its work!